# Push a notification which user is typing - ios sdk

Tags: ios, notifications, chat

I'm build a chat messenger currently, how can I get the notification when the user is typing message?
I want to send the notification to other user in the same chat room and show the message typing.

It's possible that I call the API to let the server send the notification to user at the same chat room but without pop up the notification, just directly update the text user is typing?

User -> call APi through http post -> server push notification to the same chat room user

It's slow performance, can I get a best performance beside method aove?